# Change Rubymine Rspec Color

Tags: colors, rspec, rspec2, rubymine

Im using Rspec for Testing, but CAN'T find how to change the grey color in to Red and Green.
Im testing so much that -especially when an error occurs- im having a hard time reading the passed and failures.

Any help would be nice :)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details, a screenshot?

Comment: I tried to upload a screenshot but i dont have enough reputation yet.
The Problem is that in Rubymine you have this console where you can run your Rspec Tests. And everything is in gray. Although Rubymine lets you customize almost everything, i can't find THIS option. I know that it can be done, but dont know how :)

Comment: @The Mini John: You should still be able to add the URL of the screenshot as plain text to your question.

Comment: Just gained the Reputation to upload the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it running by doing the following two things:

1. In your **run/debug configurations**, enter `-c` in the `Runner options` field
2. In your `spec_helper.rb`, add the following code:

   ```
   RSpec.configure do |config|
     config.tty = true
   end
   ```

Additional info: http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rspec-users/2011-January/019327.html

Comment: Hey, did what you said but somehow its not showing up :( -> http://pastebin.com/aNSY91vi Thats my Spec_helper File

Comment: Could you maybe upload a screenshot of your run configurations to some imagehoster and post it here?

Comment: Mmh, looks fine to me. I am on Mac, though, so maybe that has something to do with it? Sorry, I don't have any other idea.

Comment: Well, at least that's the right way to do it, I'm upvoting it so others can see. Thanks..

Comment: For me adding `-c` to the runner options didn't work, but if I type `rspec spec -c` at the terminal instead of just `rspec spec` it runs in color.

Comment: If you add `config.color_enabled = true` to your `RSpec.configure` block, you don't have to do step 1. However neither of these things are working for me (I can run tests with color from the terminal, but not from the integrated test runner). Don't know what's up with that.

Comment: I posted an issue with JetBrains support, and they told me that coloring rspec output was not possible. I'm posting a feature request now.

Answer (score 1):

Inside spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color = true
end
```

Comment: the question is specific to RubyMine's IDE Settings. Thanks tho .